# How to integrate news feed with bubble.is platform to perform functionality of getstream

Tags: getstream-io

I m build a social network using bubble.is platform but not able to fiqure out how to integrate news feed and notification system in bubble.is platform from the getstream.io platform

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Nick here from Stream. I'm not familiar with Bubble.js, however, it looks like it simply listens to DOM events. That said, you should be able to integrate Stream.js the same way that you would with any other framework (`react`, `angular`, etc.). Just import `stream.js`, initialize the client-side code, and on specific events, emit an event to `bubble.js`. If you want to take an action based off of Bubble.js (like store in `Stream Analytics`), you'd just fire an event to `stream.js` when an event happens in `bubble.js`. Hopefully, that helps out a bit. For more information on integrating with JavaScript, have a look at our docs here: https://getstream.io/docs/js/

Comment: bubble.is is not a framework it a visual programming platform where I m build my app which includes news feed and notification system.'bubble.is' is the website url You can once visit to know and plz explore if you something about it.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. It looks like a website builder, which will keep you pretty limited in regards to what you are able to do. Looking at the docs, I don't see a clear way to integrate third-party services such as Stream. From what the docs say, you will need to create a plugin of sorts to work with Bubble. https://bubble.is/developers

Answer (score 0):

parsons,

I second an implementation with bubble.is, that would be great.

Building a plugin shouldn't be too much work, but bring getstream.io to the non-coders.

Keep us posted on the progress :)